# Building a Mikva Upstairs

Tags: science, mikvah-ritual-bath, contemporary-halacha

Every Mikva I am personally familiar with is on the ground floor (first floor) or basement of its building.

Let's say a congregation owns a one story building they use as their shul. They agree to build a Mikva and this is the land they own. Is it feasible for them to build a Mikva by adding a floor to their building?

Are there any major Halachik or engineering issues with building a Mikva on the second floor?

> "General knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism" - is on topic as per this [meta post](http://Judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There chabad center in Pittsburgh has their mikvah on the second floor

Comment: Kopitshnitz shul in brooklyn has a mikva on the first floor with a basement underneath.

Comment: It's heavy. Most gyms don't have pools upstairs for the same reason. Most people don't have basements under garages for the same reason and a Mikvah weighs more than a car after all

Comment: I haven't seen or heard of any halachic restrictions regarding the "height location" of a mikvah. Hotels have rooftop pools. If they want to have a rooftop mikvah / tanning salon / spa combo - I think that would be a novel idea. I'm unaware of any place that has that, but, if they can fulfill all the halachic mikvah requirements and *tzniut* for the rest, go for it. The "engineering" challenges are probably little different than what you would need for a pool that's above ground level. Routing pipes, preventing leakage / flooding, drainage, etc. You're going against gravity after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no halachik issues with this. The Chortkov Shul in Manchester, UK is being built with a Mikva on the upper floor.

Answer (score 10):

**There is no Halachic issue**

SA YD 201.7 Rema

> הגה: מותר לעשותו על הגג ובלבד שלא יהיה תוך כלי או אבן אחת שחקקו ולבסוף קבעו אבל חבור אבנים הרבה לא מקרי כלי (תשובת הרשב"א סימן ת"ת):‏

Its allowed to make it on the roof, but not in a container or a stone that was already inground before to be fixed. However stone assembly is not a utensil.